# Need help to export SQL and re-import?

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm running in to some trouble when it comes to exporting my Magento 1.7 Database (MySQL) I've fully exported everything as-is using MySQL workbench, however - when I try to import to another Magento installation; it fails.

Is there any specific I should be looking for? And do the Database names on the old and new Magento installation need to be the same? If so, would the keys need to match?

For info -  I'm running from 1.7 Magento with a broken core installation as our last tech guy wasn't too good; and trying to re-import the Database in to a 1.9 Installation; I've tested individual tables and they run just fine, however, using PHPMyAdmin to export and import through every table is something that WILL take a long time, especially as we have a constantly growing userbase and customerbase.

Any help would be really, really helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: when you say 'it fails' can you elaborate?  mysql error? magento error?

Comment: The main error I get is that it says "Using password - NO" in the log. When I entered the password and stored it in Vault, it should be fine... I can export from my old Magento installation just fine. But, importing with the MySQL Workbench in to the database for the new installation will just fail with "Using Password - NO" and "Acess Denied" to user.

Comment: mysql workbench user permissions issue then.  mb isnt great at handling large data sets, do you have access to the server directly?  much easier to take a mysql dump and restore that way

Comment: I do, but I also just noticed in my error log that it says "Access Denied to p_usr_2819292" which is the name of the OLD database; not the new one. The new one has a different name, it's almost like MySQL workbench is trying to access the SQL backup with my credentials and then upload the data. Could this be something that occurs?

Comment: sounds like your mysql dump has the database create statements included.

Comment: I have tried without the "create" tags included; but I cannot do anything.

Comment: I am still not having much luck with this - I am not sure what is causing this, I have tried with tags, without tags, with locks, without locks, etc. Nothing works for me. If you could email me direct - marxzellphil@gmail.com that would be really helpful. Thanks for your help!